# How to display a text message after onClick in react JS?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I am pretty new to ReactJS. I have created a Form that accepts a two inputs and has a button that invokes the onclick() function. I want to display a simple message like "Action complete" below the Form when the onclick() function is complete. I don't want to use alert, but display the message on the webpage itself.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: check this : https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You can either create an element with JS and append it to the form body or you can have an invisible div/p/whatever element that gets his text modified inside the onclick function and its css class/css style too so that it appears. If you need specific code solutions you can paste your code here :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into state hooks with react, they are found here

> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

It sounds like you may want something similar to the following;

```
const Search = () => {
  const [showResults, setShowResults] = React.useState(false)
  const onClick = () => setShowResults(true)
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" onClick={onClick} />
      { showResults ? <Results /> : null }
    </div>
  )
}

const Results = () => (
  <div id="results">
    Some Results
  </div>
)
```